# Active Desktop cannot be restored on Win XP

Tags: windows-xp, restore, file-recovery

This is more of a major annoyance than anything that's stopping me from doing my work, but I somehow seem to have had Active Desktop on my work XP machine get corrupted and now can't get it back working again.

I've tried browsing to C:\Documents and Settings\%my-user-name%\Application Data\Microsoft\Internet Explorer and changing, deleting or replacing the Desktop.htt file, but it's not achieving anything.

The error I was previously getting when trying to click the "Restore my active desktop" button was:

> Internet Explorer Script Error
>
> An error has occurred in the script on
>   this page.
>
> Line: 65 Char: 1 Error: Object doesn't
>   support this action Code: 0 URL:
>   file://C:/Documents%20and%20Settings//Application
>   %20Data/Microsoft/Internet%20Explorer/Desktop.htt

Any ideas?

Comment: See [this near duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/53530/windows-desktop-background-all-white-after-cold-reboot-and-no-sutdown), which has an answer I can vouch for! (#2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using Internet Explorer 7 or higher? then this might be of interest to you:

> - Synchronization of Active Desktop with online content is no longer
>     supported.
> - The ability to restore Active Desktop if software or the operating
>     system stops responding is no longer
>     supported.

*[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa740486.aspx)*

If you're using IE6, then keep in mind that *.htt files are a not uncommon means to infect a system, scan for viruses and malware.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am new here and this is a very old post but such an ongoing problem Elsewhere on the web .....

I wanted to post my solution I came up with about 8 years ago .

all you have to do is set your desktop wallpaper to one of the built-in wallpapers that comes with XP go ahead and reboot .
that wallpaper will be shown then go ahead and choose the wallpaper you want on your desktop .

the HTT error comes from you having moved your Previous wallpaper you selected .

you don't have to get into any scripts or deleting profiles I promise